# Why am I getting an error when assigning a bsoncxx::document to another bsoncxx::document?

Tags: c++, bson, mongo-cxx-driver

Using various options, I'm attempting to build a compound query using `bsoncxx::builder::basic::document` objects. So I can build

```cpp
auto these_guys = bsoncxx::builder::basic::document{};
these_guys.append( kvp("Name", "Smith") );
```

and

```cpp
auto those_guys = bsoncxx::builder::basic::document{};
those_guys.append( kvp("Name", "Jones") );
```

and then based on some parameters

```cpp
auto full_query = bsoncxx::builder::basic::document{};
if (these && those)
{
    full_query.append(kvp("$and", make_array(these_guys , those_guys)));
}
else if (these)
{
    full_query = these_guys;   // <--- E1776 here
} 
else if (those)
{
    full_query = those_guys;   // <--- E1776 here
}
```

Using Visual Studio 2017, I'm getting the error

```
Error (active)  E1776   function "bsoncxx::v_noabi::builder::basic::document::operator=(const bsoncxx::v_noabi::builder::basic::document &) throw()" (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
```

It's my understanding from the documentation that I should be able to make this assignment. Please correct my thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://mongocxx.org/api/current/classbsoncxx_1_1builder_1_1basic_1_1document.html#aea7f85f7945cdb3864983bd669ec0cbe):

> document &    operator= (document &&doc) noexcept
>
> Move assignment operator.

There's no mention of a copy assignment operator. Since a move assignment operator was defined the copy assignment operator is automatically deleted.

So you have to use move assignment:

```
full_query = std::move(these_guys);
```

Comment: Clearly I didn't understand the docs when it says "Move assignment operator". That's on me. I incorrectly believed that `operator=` was for copying as I was trying to do. Thanks for the help in understanding.